# Getting the memory metrics of Apache Ignite and create dash board

Tags: graph, server, ignite, metrics

I need to get the memory metrics (like what is the maximum memory, how much memory is currently used by server, how much memory is available and CPU usage) from Apache Ignite server. If persistence is enabled then i need to get the disk usage as well. I need to get the information for every particular time. from that data i need to derive some dash board(graph). can anyone please suggest some idea for that?

Comment: Have you tried using Web Console? It is a ready-made dashboard for Apache Ignite.

Comment: is web console open source or paid?

Comment: There is completely open Apache Ignite web console, and there is GridGain web console which is not open but completely free to use.

Comment: Where I found Apache ignite web console?  Can you please share the link?

Comment: I've added link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridGain web console may act as monitoring dashboard.

It can be [downloaded from GridGain](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/download#webconsole) web site and is free to use.

Comment: is Ignite web console and gridgain web console same? in this redirect to gridgain?

Comment: is ignite web console doesn't shows dash board independently?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has dashboard, I'm a bit weak regarding its functionality.